# reload tableview without image in cell reloads

Tags: swift, tableview, uitableview, reloaddata, kingfisher

I have a tableview and cells within that it has imageview and it gets image from server and whenever user scroll down to end of tableview,tableview's data gets reloaded but my problem is cells image is going to download image from server again whenever tableview gets reloaded, this is my code:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pizzacell", for: indexPath) as! CustomPizzaCell
let imgurl = URL(string: "\(BaseUrl)//assests/products/imgs/\(MainMenu.cellarray[indexPath.row].img)")
cell.pizzaimg.kf.setImage(with: imgurl, options: [.downloadPriority(Float(indexPath.row)),.transition(.flipFromTop(1.0)),.forceRefresh,.processor(processor)])
if indexPath.row == MainMenu.cellarray.count-1 {
        if !isendoftable {
            MainMenu.start += 5
            MainMenu.end += 5
            var parameters: Parameters = ["START": "\(MainMenu.start)"]
            parameters["END"] = "\(MainMenu.end)"
            parameters["TYPE"] = "\(MainMenu.type)"
            print(parameters)
            ApiManager.request(Address: "\(BaseUrl)/admin/Android/getLastProducts", method: .post, parameters: parameters) { json in
                self.stopAnimating()
                if json == nil {
                    let popupDialog = PopupDialog(title: "خطای دسترسی به سرور", message: "")
                    let btn = DefaultButton(title: "تلاش مجدد"){}
                    btn.titleFont = UIFont(name: "IRANSans(FaNum)", size: 15)
                    if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad {
                        btn.titleFont = UIFont(name: "IRANSans(FaNum)", size: 17)
                    }
                    popupDialog.addButton(btn)
                    self.present(popupDialog, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                else {
                    if (json?.array?.isEmpty)! {
                        MainMenu.start = 0
                        MainMenu.end = 5
                        self.isendoftable = true
                    }
                    for item in (json?.array)! {
                        let piiiza = MainMenu.cell(id: item["id"].description, title: item["title"].description, img: item["img"].description)
                        MainMenu.cellarray.append(piiiza)
                    }
                    tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
```

Comment: Guess: `.forceRefresh` doesn't use cache, and reload instead?

Comment: Why are you calling `reloadData` from within `cellForRowAt`? Very, very bad.

Comment: Basically you need to add the image to your data source and check *does-the-image-exist* and I completely agree with rmaddy:  *Calling `reloadData` from within `cellForRowAt`* is *very, very bad*.

Comment: Yeah...this is all kinds of nasty. It looks like you'll be infinitely making that API call and reloading the table. You should probably rethink this :-\.

Comment: @vadian because I'm updating tableview whenever user gets to the last of tableview , new data is added to tableview ...is there other way to do the same thing?

Comment: Please read about the MVC (model-view-controller) pattern, it's one of the basic concepts for table views.

Comment: so for doing this when Should I reload data so my previous loaded image not get loaded again

Comment: Once again *you need to add the image to your data source model and check if the image exists*. If yes skip loading the image.

Comment: if I dont reloaddata in cell for row at... when Should I reloaddata when I want to know when user gets to last of tableview or another way of asking how can I know I am in the last of tableview cell (or scrollview)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Kingfisher` which already handle image caching. Loading a new image when tableView get reloaded should only be reading cache.

You need to remove the `.forceRefresh` in this line:

```
cell.pizzaimg.kf.setImage(with: imgurl, options: [.downloadPriority(Float(indexPath.row)),.transition(.flipFromTop(1.0)),.forceRefresh,.processor(processor)])
```

According to the docs, `forceRefresh`ignore the cache and downloaded from the URL again. You can see this [here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Kingfisher/3.5.2/Enums/KingfisherOptionsInfoItem.html#/s:FO10Kingfisher25KingfisherOptionsInfoItem12forceRefreshFMS0_S0_).

> forceRefresh
>
> If set, Kingfisher will ignore the cache and try to fire a download task for the resource.

Comment: I need forcerefresh because Image on server gets updated and beside this I want handle this problem somehow for other project that I dont use kingfisher

Comment: The question you have now is that how to prevent loading of UIImage when tableView is reloaded. The way to do it is via `cache`. Without `Kingfisher` you still need to setup some `cache` to do it. 

Secondly, You say you need `forceRefresh` but you do not want to reload the image when tableView is reload, this don't make sense to the question you have ask. If you need to refresh it only after a certain time then you can set some cache expiring time on the image.

Comment: can't I just add new data not reloading whole tableview? so my previous cells will remain and not loaded

Comment: You can't do it this way. `UITableViewCell` are being reuse. Therefore what is not visible now is being reuse as a new `cell` that is appearing. These is something Apple have design. You just can't do it with `UITableView`.